# textbox without decimal causing issue with > sign

Tags: vb.net, xaml, textbox

I have a text box in which i don't want decimal, so I am restricting user to key in decimal by checking in keydown event.
However, this is causing issue with ">" sign as user is not able to enter ">" sign in text box.

```
If Not e.Handled AndAlso e.Key = Key.Decimal OrElse e.PlatformKeyCode = 190 OrElse e.PlatformKeyCode = 110 Then
        If e.Key <> Key.Back Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
End If
```

Any inputs how can i solve?

Comment: If you just bind it to an `int` property on the viewmodel the problem is solved.

Comment: did you see this question?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539492/wpf-textbox-validation-c-sharp

Comment: I was able to solve this by using (Keyboard.Modifiers <> ModifierKeys.Shift AndAlso e.PlatformKeyCode = 190)