# How to set min length for texbox?

Tags: wpf

I want to set "Min Length" property for My TextBox in C# - WPF.
In fact I have a TextBox in my window and I want to limit it to only 10 character.
I set max length to 10 but I don't find min length property!

Comment: You need to write your own validation for that. http://stackoverflow.com/a/43029089/424129

Comment: There is  no min. Please elaborate, what are you trying to do

Comment: I want to limit my texbox to only 10 character length. not more. not fewer. only 10.

Comment: `MaxLength` sets the visual length of the control, it has nothing to do with character count. You need to implement your own validation for the control, as Ed Plunkett suggested.

Comment: I think "Ed Plunkett" answered good. But I don't know regex's code for min length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you something like this:

On the event Lost Focus, you handle when the user left the TextBox:

**XAML:**

```
<TextBox LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus" />
```

Later with the Length property you set the minimum of characters that you expect.

**C#:**

```
private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (((TextBox)sender).Text.Length < 5)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You need to write at least 5 characters");
    }
}
```

This is how it should look:

[image: example]

Comment: You have written the same answer as that of mine. What's different in this?

Answer (score 1):

Create one property "MinLength" in your view model.

Attach a lost focus event handler to your textbox and inside it, put the check for minimum number of characters using above declared property.  If textbox length is <10, then again set focus in same textbox.

Xaml:

```
<TextBox LostFocus="UIElement_OnLostFocus"></TextBox>
```

Code behind:

```
private void UIElement_OnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // check condition here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have had the same problem and solved it this way ... Maybe it's not a nice programming style!? :)

```
int (name) = 0;
(name) = (textbox).TextLength;

if((name) >= (min input you like){
(do something)}

else {ErrorMessage)}
```