# TextBox only allow enter certain range of numbers, but its not accept some correct value

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

Good evening,

trying to make WPF textbox accept only double value between 3 and 2813

in the code below ,I can't write any value start with 1 or 2

like 11,22,113,215,2008

```
private bool IsValid(string str)
{
    double i;
    return double.TryParse(str, out i) && i >= 3 && i <= 2813;
}

private void L_Text_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = !IsValid(((TextBox)sender).Text + e.Text);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried breaking the return statement of IsValid up into multiple statements and check the actual value of i and the str? Have you made sure that the input can be parsed to a double correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PreviewTextInput** occurs whenever the user presses a key. So we can't know whether the user intends to write "2" or "22" at this moment.
To evaluate the value we must be sure that the user finished writing. You can use **LostFocus** event for this purpose.

```
private bool IsValid(string str)
{
    double i;         
    return double.TryParse(str, out i) && i >= 3 && i <= 2813;
}
private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var txt = sender as TextBox;
    if (!IsValid((txt.Text)))
    {
        //invalid delete text
        txt.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Detailed validation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37255232/1431001

Comment: I tried your code , but the textbox now accept smaller than 3
and its wrong value.

Comment: Actually, PreviewKeyInput was not a suitable place to validate so, I modified the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things you could do

1. You could evaluate if it starts with a specific character, and then parse that
2. You could use https://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/double-textbox/getting-started