# How to check if every Textbox in WPF app is filled? (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, textbox, controls

I have six textboxes in my WPF app, and I want to check if every single one of them is filled (that means the **textboxes contains at least one letter, number, etc. (datatype doesn't matter!)**)

When not, I want to pop up Messagebox to inform the user to check them once again (that's just for context, I know how to do this specific thing). How do I check that? Everywhere I've searched, they somehow did it but in Windows Forms, which is not what I need, obviously.

Comment: Could this post answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539492/implement-validation-for-wpf-textboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either check whether they have inputs or check them for specific input types (ie. validation). For validation I would suggest you read the following question and answers.

[Implement Validation for WPF TextBoxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539492/implement-validation-for-wpf-textboxes)

But if you want to check whether a textbox has input or not, you can either check with "(string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.Text))" or "(textBox1.TextLength == 0)" or if you don't want "space" you can check with "(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox.Text)).

You can traverse your WPF xml in various ways but I'd recommend following answer

[Find all controls in WPF Window by type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974598/find-all-controls-in-wpf-window-by-type)

Comment: That second part looks very promising and like something that I wanted, thanks, just one another question, do I have to do this for every single textbox in the code or is there any way to do it in one codeblock? (with some loop or method or anything?)

Comment: Second link shows how you can get them all in an ienumerable<TextBox> or any type you want. And since you can then do a foreach loop you can check them all in a block of code

Comment: Yeah, sorry, somehow overlooked that. Thank you for your answer.