# Is there a certain binding I can use for my custom TextBox Style so when I access Text property it equals whatever the user types in the textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to grab the timesInput text property every time the user changes the text in the box and basically make sure there's only numbers being typed in, but say I try to Output the text to console, Its saying the text property of textbox is equal to "".

Ive tried putting updatetrigger in the bindings and updating it explicitly but its still not updating.

This is my TextBox style that apply to all my TextBoxes.

```
<TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox"
                                Background="Transparent"
                                VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                                BorderThickness="0"/>
```

Heres an example of one the TextBoxes im trying to access

```
<TextBox 
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                x:Name="timesInput"
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                                VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                Width="60"
                                Height="20"
                                TextChanged="timesInput_TextChanged"
                                Style="{StaticResource TextBox}"
                                Text="{Binding myTextProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                                </TextBox>
```

And heres where im trying the access the text propertry

```
private void timesInput_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            
            Trace.WriteLine(timesInput.Text);
            TextBoxViewModel TextBoxText = new TextBoxViewModel();

            try
            {
                string pattern = @"^\d+$";
                string numberCount = TextBoxText.myTextProperty;
                string times = numberCount;

                if (!Regex.IsMatch(times, pattern))
                {
                    // If the text doesn't match the pattern, filter out non-digit characters
                    times = new string(times.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
                    numberCount = times;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(exception.Message);
            }
```

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539492/implement-validation-for-wpf-textboxes

Comment: That's weird code. You're instantiating a viewmodel in an event? How's anything else supposed to get at that viewmodel? You should use a behavior, maybe coerce the dependency property value or just act in the viewmodel setter. But bind to a property in the window's viewmodel.

Comment: "my TextBox style" is a Control Template? If yes, then you created the TextBox Template incorrectly. In the TextBox Template, the `<ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" ..../>` element is responsible for displaying text. You don't have this element in your template. Therefore, your Template behaves somewhat unpredictably.

Comment: A “dirty” solution to the problem with your template is to bind the Text property of the internal TextBox to the Text property of the element using this Template. For this you need a binding `Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"`.

Comment: EldHasp what would be a better solution